# PermGen space - maven m2e tomcat7

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, out-of-memory

I try to deploy a war on tomcat with maven.
When I run with maven goal `tomcat7: run`.
Tomcat seems to launch maven connects to the database, then I have the right to error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I use m2e, eclipse and tomcat.
I tried to add in POM.xml :

```
<configuration>
  <systemProperties>
    <JAVA_OPTS>-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</JAVA_OPTS>
  </systemProperties>
</configuration>
```

And in the JRE parameter of maven :

```
-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

But nothing happens ..

Do you have any idea? Another way to solve that error ?

Comment: Verify catalina is actually running with that `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` command line param, it should work, if not increase it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use eclipse IDE than with use of it you can change the VM argument

```
double click on the server > open Lunch Configuration > Arguments > VM Arguments
```

and append below two lines in your VM Arguments field

```
-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

it will sure solve your problem

Comment: wecome:) !! very useful thing

Answer (score 2):

Add these parameters in config file -

```
MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

Alternatively, you can set them using command prompt if you run from command line directly like -

`set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m`

Comment: what config file pls? context.xml? pom.xml?

Comment: Maven config file which will be m2.conf OR settings.xml. First try to apply this on command prompt.

Comment: tomcat-folder/bin/catalina.sh

Comment: <forkMode>pertest</forkMode> 
 <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m</argLine> this for pom.xml

Comment: <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx512m</argLine> run too ^^

Comment: this is more likely a m2e problem. increase m2e space by adding -Xms128M -Xmx512M into run configurations --> jre tab --> vm argument

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in command prompt :
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError

If you are working in IDE :
Server > VM Arguments and add followings

-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Comment: Great answer with multiple possible solutions! Instead of linking to an [explanation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError) consider a link accompanied by a summary of the relevant info from that solution.

Your solution could also be made a bit more readable if you used backticks ` around your `code`